# Smoothing of a 2D Empirical Distribution

Tags: estimation, k-nearest-neighbour, smoothing

I have a number of data points $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^2$ with corresponding values $x \in \mathbb{N}$.

I am assuming the $x$ are realisations from a distribution $f(X | \theta)$.

Given I have a lot of observations $(\theta_i, x_i)$ and the $x_i$ are ordinal, what is the best way to estimate $\hat{f}(X | \theta)$ by smoothing an empirical distribution?

I currently use a K nearest neighbours approach i.e. if I observe a new $\theta$, I find the value of the $x_i$ for its k nearest neighbours and use these as my empirical distribution, but I feel there should be a better (smoother) way.

Comment: Do you know much about kernel density estimation?

Comment: Ah yes, this seems to be what I was looking for.

Comment: Having said that, I am not sure now how to smooth for the parameters $\theta$.